# Is it possible to use write() in file opened with O_APPEND mode?

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    FILE * fp;
    char buf[128];
    int fd = open("/home/pdave/Downloads/ccode/fileout1",O_CREAT);
    printf("fd after creat:%d",fd);
    close(fd);
    fd = open("/home/pdave/Downloads/ccode/fileout1",O_APPEND);
    printf("fd after append:%d",fd);
    int more=1;
    int ret=0;
    while(more){
        puts("enter text:");
        scanf("%s",buf);
        puts(buf);
        ret=write(fd,buf,128);
        printf("ret:%d",ret);
        puts("more?");
        scanf("%d",&more);
    }
}
```

The above tries to write characters to a file opened with the open function in `O_APPEND` mode. It works when it is opened with `O_WRONLY` mode but not when it is opened in `O_APPEND`. How can I append to it without opening with "w" and then using seek to `SEEK_END` and then `fputs` to the file or something like that?

Comment: nice. it appends. but it is writing some obscure ascii characters. i suppose it is due to the length of the buffer?

Comment: If you aren't entering more than 127 characters per execution of `scanf("%s",buf);`, it may be a character set issue of some sort.

Comment: the error in it was that i was writing 128 bytes whereas i should be writing in strlen(buf) bytes.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue if your buffer already contains a null-terminated string, as `write` is supposed to stop writing when it encounters the null character even if it hasn't written 128 bytes. That value is supposed to be the maximum number of characters to write. Here's an example: http://ideone.com/OVANgi

Answer (score 1):

Use `O_WRONLY | O_APPEND`, you still need the file access mode. (For some [most?] compilers, not including a file access flag will cause the file to be treated as read-only, and if not then you'd have an `EINVAL` error.)

Comment: Most if not all UN\*Xes define `O_RDONLY` as 0, so not including a file access flag is the same as including `O_RDONLY`.  (That's not a compiler issue on UN\*X, it's an operating system issue; any compiler that gives a different value for `O_RDONLY` than the "standard" compiler would be broken.)