# write(): Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, posix, file-descriptor

I'm trying to learn basic IO functions in POSIX, I wrote the following code, but it does not work and a "Bad file descriptor" error is returned when I try to execute the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{

    int nfd;
    ssize_t ret;

    mode_t mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG;

    nfd = openat(AT_FDCWD, "idx.txt", O_APPEND | O_SYNC | O_CREAT, mode);

    if (-1 == nfd)
    {
        perror("openat()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = write(nfd, "HELLO", 5);

    if (-1 == ret)
    {
        perror("write()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(nfd);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to write to the file in O_APPEND mode. But:

```
$ touch idx.txt # it does not work even if the file does not exist already
$ ./a.out
write(): Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use write() in file opened with O\_APPEND mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315363/is-it-possible-to-use-write-in-file-opened-with-o-append-mode)

Comment: 'touch idx.txt' , if the file already exists, only updates the modification time on the file.  if the file does not already exist, creates and entry on a 'inode', and sets the modification time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not telling the system that you want to write to the file, adding O_WRONLY or O_RDWR to the flags makes it work.